# Actual definition of electric flux

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law

I am currently studying electrostatics and I've come across confusing definitions of electric flux.

One definition is *the number of field lines crossing a surface*. However, I have a hard time making sense of this definition, as field lines are only a conceptual visualisation and do not actually exist. Hence, you can't really "count" how many of them passes through a surface.

Another definition that I've been taught is the magnitude of the component of the electric field normal to the surface. Hence:

$$\phi=\vec E \cdot \vec A = \Vert\vec E\Vert \Vert\vec A\Vert \cos \theta$$

Where $\vec A$ is the area vector

However, if this latter definition is correct, then shouldn't flux be defined as $\frac{\vec E \cdot \vec A}{\Vert \vec A \Vert}$, since $\vec E \cdot \vec A$ by itself gives you the magnitude of the component, multiplied by the magnitude of $\vec A$?

What, then, is the actual definition of electric flux?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_flux

Comment: *Another definition that I've been taught is the magnitude of the component of the electric field normal to the surface.* That’s incorrect; you probably misunderstood. It’s the normal component *times the area*. And, in general, you have to integrate over infinitesimal areas if the field isn’t uniform or the surface is curved.

Comment: Note that there are an *uncountably infinite number* of field lines passing through a surface. One passes through every point! So defining flux as “the number of field lines crossing the surface” doesn’t work.

Comment: @Ghoster Thank you for your clarification! I just wanted to confirm that it's actually multiplied by the area, hence the dot product.

Comment: Yes it is multiplied by the area to get the total flux across the whole surface.

Answer (score 1):

Your second definition is the correct one, though since surfaces are generally curved we write:

$$ d\Phi = \mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{A} $$

then we integrate over the surface to get the total flux. You are quite correct that the flux depends on the area, but we normally want the total flux e.g. if we are using Gauss's law we need the total flux over the whole surface. You can, if you wish, divide by the area to get a flux density.

You are also correct that field lines are just a conceptual aid and they cannot be counted, so we cannot count the number of field lines through a surface. You could define a field line density as proportional to $\mathbf{E}$ and use that in the calculation. Then just divide by the constant of proportionality at the end to covert the *field line flux* to the *electric flux*. But this ends up the same as just integrating $\mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{A}$.

Comment: *Your second definition is the correct one.* The second definition of flux stated by the OP is “the magnitude of the component of the electric field normal to the surface”. That statement is *not* correct, which caused the OP’s confusion about which equation was correct.

Answer (score -2):

Represent $1 V/m$ field strength as 1 electric field line and then you'll clearly see that electric flux IS countable.

Your suggestion of $\frac{\vec E \cdot \vec A}{\Vert \vec A \Vert}
 $ is flawed since it's equivalent to

$\frac{\vec E \cdot S\vec n}{S} = E \cos \theta $ and so you are loosing proportionality to the surface area, hence your definition is not an electric flux, but field strength projection along surface normal.

Comment: How many field lines are $\sqrt2$ V/m? Do you think the real numbers are countable?

Comment: @Ghoster Agnius is using the approach in my second paragraph i.e. setting the field line density proportional to the field using any convenient constant of proportionality (he uses unity). So his answer is fine if a little unclear.

Comment: @JohnRennie Your own answer correctly says that field lines cannot be counted. How do you conclude that saying electric flux is countable is “fine”? I think it’s nonsense.

Comment: @Ghoster yes but you can say the field line density = αE for some undefined constant α and then at the end α disappears because you divide through by it. You cannot define α because field lines cannot be counted, but that's OK as it cancels in the final result. So you can just choose an arbitrary value like α = 1.

Comment: @JohnRennie My downvote remains. There is no sense in which electric flux is [countable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set).

Comment: @JohnRennie I don’t understand how there can be any argument about this. The flux can theoretically be any real number of volt-meters. The real numbers are not a countable set.

Comment: @Ghoster Although unduly complicated and potentially misleading, it is possible to make sense of the idea of counting line fields. It is enough to assign a large but finite number $N$ of representative line fields to each elementary charge, uniformly distributed on the solid angle at a short distance from the charge. For any finite number, everything works, and eventually, one can make $N\rightarrow \infty$. It is equivalent to stating Riemann's definition of the integral for the flux in words. ANd to Rennie's definition of density of lines through the field value.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 Which of these statements do you disagree with, and why? 1. The flux can be any real number of volt-meters. 2. The real numbers are not a countable set.

Comment: _How many field lines are $\sqrt2$
 V/m?_ Depends on the chosen line density constant $N/E$. Then you multiply this by $E$ and get number of field lines $N$ back. Sure, if chosen scaling constant is too rough then you'll get in general that $N \in \mathbb R$

Comment: @Ghoster, I agree with your statements 1. and 2. What I am trying to say can be restated as 1. A sequence of rational numbers can approximate every real number. 2. every rational number $n/m$, once $m$ has been chosen,  can be put in correspondence with the integer $n$ if we multiply it by $m$. Complicated? Potentially misleading? Yes, I agree. Impossible? Certainly possible.

Comment: It is interesting that for nearly 200 years Physicists did "count" field lines and produced the laws of electromagnetism which are used today.